# AngularJS + Coffeescript - 'Hello World' directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I can't make the simplest of directives work in my AngularJS + Coffeescript project.

I have this code in directives.coffee:

```
'use strict'
app_name = "myApp"
app = angular.module "#{app_name}.directives", []

# Directive to include the version number of my project
app.directive 'appVersion', [
'version', (version) ->
    (scope, element, attrs) ->
    element.text version
]

# Hello world directive
app.directive 'hello', () ->
    restict: 'E'
    template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
```

And in my template, when I do

```
<span app-version></span>
<hello></hello>
```

then the version number appears (0.1), showing that the first directive works properly, but the  tag does not get replaced by anything.

Any idea what I did wrong?

I also tried this, which didn't work either:

```
# Hello world directive
app.directive 'hello', ->
    class Habit
        constructor: ->
            restict: 'E'
            template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
restict: 'E'
```

should be

```
restrict: 'E'
```

Working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8TifpS2EmYPLo4wl7YtK?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

You can also write your Angular Directive in CoffeeScript like this which I think is cleaner:

```
class MyDirective
    constructor: (myService) ->
        // Constructor stuff
        @controller = MyController
        @controllerAs = 'ctrl'
    restrict: 'E'
    replace: true
    scope:
        attributeStuff: '='
    link: (scope, element, attr) ->

angular.module('my_module').directive 'MyDirective', (myService) ->
    new MyDirective(myService)
```

Comment: do you have any examples of injecting services into a directive using this syntax? I like the style here (versus one we're using which uses an `@option` function to bootstrap the directive) but was struggling with adapting it on my own.

Comment: Hi @virtualandy. You can inject services like this: angular.module('my_module').directive 'MyDirective', ($http) ->
    new MyDirective($http)