# Use CoffeeScript's class in AngularJS directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript

While creating AngularJS directives with CoffeeScript I was using this approach:

```
angular
.module('MyApp', [])
.directive 'myDirective', ->
restrict: 'E'
controllerAs: 'ctrl'
controller: ->
  new class
    constructor: ->
      @value = 3
```

This code works with Angular 1.2.14—[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/moyufa/4/edit)—but does not with 1.3.0—[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/moyufa/6/edit). I don't have any error in the console, simply it does nothing. It appears that the controller is an empty object.

Comment: This works pretty well for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172394/javascript-doest-convert-angular-ui-datepicker-date-to-utc-correctly/29030439#29030439

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered almost the same question in this thread: [AngularJS + Coffeescript - 'Hello World' directive not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009065/angularjs-coffeescript-hello-world-directive-not-working/26468540#26468540). I like keeping my Angular objects as proper CoffeeScript classes. The key is to wrap the `new Directive()` inside a function block.

```
class MyDirective
    constructor: (myService) ->
        // Constructor stuff
        @controller = MyController
        @controllerAs = 'ctrl'
    restrict: 'E'
    replace: true
    scope:
        attributeStuff: '='
    link: (scope, element, attr) ->

angular.module('my_module').directive 'MyDirective', (myService) ->
    new MyDirective(myService)
```

Comment: With your method it seems not possible to use the `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: I see, but still I don't understand the advantage of doing that.

Comment: Well I like to either have everything in classes or everything in Angular modules, not a mixture of both. And since I prefer to write Controllers and Services as classes I want the same for Directives. Consistency is king

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research: it seems that in Angualar 1.3.0 if you use `controllerAs` Angular will take `controller` and execute `new` on it. So this code fixes the problem:

```
angular
.module('MyApp', [])
.directive 'myDirective', ->
restrict: 'E'
controllerAs: 'ctrl'
controller: class
  constructor: ->
    @value = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a pattern for defining my controllers with coffeescript classes and attaching them to the directive (also defined in coffeescript) with controllerAs so I can access the class properties and methods in the template. I also defined the classes using the controller provider. This worked great in angular 1.2.15 but broke when I updated to 1.3.6.

After much debugging, I realized that angular was no longer automatically putting the object instance returned by the coffeescript class onto the scope. The fix is very simple: manually put the instantiated class object on the scope, as show below:

```
myModule.directive 'cePageHeader',  ->
  restrict: 'A'
  templateUrl: 'shared/ce-page-header.tpl.html'
  replace: true
  scope: true
  controller: 'CePageHeaderDirectiveCtrl as cePageHeaderDirCtrl'

cePageHeaderDirectiveModule.controller 'CePageHeaderDirectiveCtrl',
(UserModel, $scope) ->
  $scope.cePageHeaderDirCtrl =
  new class CePageHeaderDirectiveCtrl
    constructor: ->
      @user = UserModel

    goHome: ->
      console.log "Do something to go home"
```

Previously, the function simply returned the object created by the class. Adding this one line fixed the problem with 1.3.6:

```
$scope.cePageHeaderDirCtrl =
```

BTW, in the template I can access my class object like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="cePageHeaderDirCtrl.goHome()">
  Go Home
```

Without the manually assignment to the $scope, $scope.cePageHeaderDirCtrl = {}, an empty object.