# Datepicker-popup formatting not working when value set initially in scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the Angular UI bootstrap date picker popup using this custom directive on Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/053VJYm1MpZUiKwFTfrT?p=preview):

```
//Module
var userModule = angular.module("userModule",['ui.bootstrap']);

//Controller
userModule.controller("sampleController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.minDate = new Date();
}]);

//Directive code
userModule.directive('datePicker', [function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngReadonly: '=?',
            minDate: '=?',
            maxDate: '=?',
            dtpRequired: '=?',
            dateOptions: '=?'
        },
        template: '<p class="input-group">' +
                    '<input type="text" style="cursor:pointer" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"' +
                        'ng-model="ngModel" is-open="opened"' +
                            'min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"' +
                                'datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"' +
                                 'ng-required="dtpRequired" close-text="Close" ng-readonly="ngReadonly" ng-click="openPopup()" />' +
                         '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openPopup($event)">' +
                                '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>' +
                        '</span>' +
                    '</p>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // check if it was defined.  If not - set a default
            $scope.dateOptions = $scope.dateOptions || {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                showWeeks: false
            };

            $scope.openPopup = function ($event) {
                if ($event !== undefined) {
                    $event.stopPropagation();
                }
                $scope.opened = true;
            };

            $scope.format = 'dd MMMM yyyy';
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            //remove the default formatter from the input directive to prevent conflict
            controller.$formatters.shift();
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is working fine and the date is formatted fine when selecting a date from the calendar popup. However if I set a date of the ng-model in the controller, the date isn't formatted as 'dd MMMM yyyy' and is returned as a date string like Sat Oct 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time). However in the Plunker, I am able to set a date in the controller and it is formatted fine. 
Here is my HTML for the date picker:

```
<date-picker ng-model="startDate.value" datepicker-options="dateOptions" min-date="minDate" ng-readonly="true"></date-picker>
```

In my controller `startDate.value = new Date();`

I'm not sure where the problem could be. The image below shows what I'm getting back.

[image: Wrong Date]

Comment: Can't reproduce this in the Plunker as you said - in the `sampleController`, set `$scope.dtpValue1 = new Date();` and the formatting appears correct ("01 August 2016"). Did you try the *exact* same code locally and have this problem?

Comment: Yeah using the same code in my project is giving me this problem

Comment: That's quite bizarre. Are you using the same versions of libraries and your browser?

Comment: Yep same bootstrap and angular versions and using chrome

Comment: I've tried it locally (not on Plunker) and still get the correct format. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 51.0.2704.103

Comment: I've tested on Chrome 48 and 52; both work as expected. Have you tried deleting your local code and copying the code in from Plunker? Perhaps there's something that you changed but didn't notice. I have a working Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/v7BXumnZQJAazpiqJsvP?p=preview) if you want to copy from it; I just added `$scope.dtpValue1 = new Date();`.

Comment: Updated to Chrome 52 and copied code over again. Still being displayed without formatting

Comment: Is there anything in the error console (press F12)?

Comment: Nothing at all. Do not know at all why it's not working

Comment: I'm very confused as well; you have the exact same directory structure, file names, code and browser but it doesn't work locally. Could you perhaps screenshot the incorrect behaviour so I can take a look?

Comment: Added a picture of what I'm getting back if I manually set date in controller

Comment: You said before you were using `startDate.value = new Date();` to set the value. If you're still doing that, how exactly did you define startDate?

Comment: `$scope.startDate = {value: new Date()};`

Comment: Right, so that's working fine. Why does your calendar show November in the screenshot rather than August though?

Comment: Ah I set the date manually in that case: `new Date("November 01, 2016")`. The same happens with just `new Date()` however

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I really have no clue what's going on. If you don't get any responses in a few days I'll try and put a bigger bounty on, because I'm really curious about what's causing this.

Comment: What OS are you using, and what language do you have set in your OS?

Comment: Windows 7 and English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this. I changed to the uib-datepicker directive from Angular-UI-Bootstrap and it now formats the date correctly when the date is set in the controller! Here's my HTML template from my directive for reference:

```
template: '<p class="input-group">' +
            '<input type="text" style="cursor:pointer" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"' +
                'ng-model="ngModel" is-open="opened"' +
                    'min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"' +
                        'datepicker-options="dateOptions"date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"' +
                         'ng-required="dtpRequired" close-text="Close" ng-readonly="ngReadonly" ng-click="openPopup()" />' +
                 '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openPopup($event)">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>' +
                '</span>' +
            '</p>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code locally and it seemed to work great without any issues.
I tried various ways of changing the date and again everything works.
There seems to be a little difference between the example in plnkr and the example you are posting, specifically  the way you are referencing the date (You are stating you are using **startDate.value = new Date();** , but in plnkr I see **ng-model="dtpValue1"** .This makes me think that there are other things that you are missing and I suggest making a complete example in a .zip file that is testable locally.  Also since there is a chance that nobody will be able to reproduce it again, it would be useful the list of all chrome extensions and operation system you have, and most importantly you should try to reproduce it on other machine and report back the results.

Generally what are expecting to work is working as expected on every machine that I have tested and I don't see a good reason why it shouldn't work.

If I was able to reproduce the issue I could put breakpoints and figure out exactly what is going on, but at the moment this is out of the question and we should focus on how to reproduce the problem.

The provided information seems insufficient to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of bootstrap UI datepicker works with string actually and you are trying to assign a javascript date object to the variable that UI bootstrap works on angular controller. they are different type of datas so it causes the error. If you try to console the type of the variable, after select a date from datepicker pop-up. you will see it is a string. So.. If you want to set a date from your controller just you need to set it as string, not a javascript object.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't the bootstrap UI datepicker handle the formatting of a JS date object?

Comment: Believe me it's a huge headache. I tried many things to do it but couldn't. It cant handle with date objects.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this directive to convert `string` form server to valid javascript format that uib-datepicker-popup need:

```
app.directive('datepickerLocaleDate', ["$rootScope", "$filter", function ($rootScope, $filter) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

         if (ngModel) {

           // convert string to valid javascript fprmat 
            setTimeout(() => {
               ngModel.$setViewValue(new Date(ngModel['$viewValue']));
            }, 3000);


            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
              return new Date(value);
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
              return value ? $filter('date')(value, 'yyyy/MM/dd') : null;
            });

         }
      }
   };
}]);
```